# Strange python error with subprocess.check_call

Tags: python, subprocess, python-3.4

I'm having a really strange error with the python `subprocess.check_call()` function. Here are two tests that should both fail because of permission problems, but the first one only returns a 'usage' (the "unexpected behaviour"):

```
# Test #1
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call(['git', 'clone', 'https://github.com/achedeuzot/project',
                       '/var/vhosts/project'], shell=True)

# Shell output
usage: git [--version] [--exec-path[=<path>]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--info-path]
           [-p|--paginate|--no-pager] [--no-replace-objects] [--bare]
           [--git-dir=<path>] [--work-tree=<path>] [--namespace=<name>]
           [-c name=value] [--help]
           <command> [<args>]

The most commonly used git commands are:
[...]
```

Now for the second test (the "expected behaviour" one):

```
# Test #2
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call(' '.join(['git', 'clone', 'https://github.com/achedeuzot/project',
                                '/var/vhosts/project']), shell=True)
# Here, we're making it into a string, but the call should be *exactly* the same.

# Shell output
fatal: could not create work tree dir '/var/vhosts/project'.: Permission denied
```

This second error is the correct one. I don't have the permissions indeed. But why is there a difference between the two calls ? I thought that using a single string or a list is the same with the `check_call()` function. I have read the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html) and various usage examples and both look correct.

Did someone have the same strange error ? Or does someone know why is there a difference in output when the commands should be exactly the same ?

Side notes: Python 3.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `shell=True` from the first one. If you carefully reread the subprocess module documentation you will see. If `shell=False` (default) the first argument is a list of the command line with arguments and all (or a string with only the command, no arguments supplied at all). If shell=True, then the first argument is a string representing a shell command line, a shell is executed, which in turn parses the command line for you and splits by white space (+ much more dangerous things you might not want it to do). **If `shell=True` and the first argument is a list, then the first list item is the shell command line, and the rest are passed as arguments to the shell, not the command**.

Unless you know you really, really need to, always let `shell=False`.

Comment: Thank you ! I missed that one ! I had used `shell=True` because another command didn't work without this option. So I just kept it for subsequent calls to `check_call`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the relevant bit from the documentation:

> If args is a sequence, the first item specifies the command string, and any additional items will be treated as additional arguments to the shell itself. That is to say, Popen does the equivalent of:
>
> `Popen(['/bin/sh', '-c', args[0], args[1], ...])`

Comment: I know that, I *want* them to be command + args... I don't see how this explains anything about the strange behaviour...

Comment: The strange behavior is because the word "clone" is being treated as an argument to `/bin/sh`, not as an argument to `git`.

Comment: Yes, but that comes from the fact that `shell=True` is in the `check_call` arguments. Without that, they are all arguments of the `git` command :)

Comment: Yes, and do you get a difference in behavior without shell=True?

Comment: Of course ! But that was the thing I missed while I was looking at examples.

Comment: Er, I think we're talking past each other. In any case, it sounds like you've got it working now.

Comment: Well it seems so. It works because I removed `shell=True`, so the list is considered as a shell command string without any additional arguments to the shell. @Anton's answer explains it very well :)

Comment: I agree about Anton's answer -- I had just been writing my answer at the same time, and thought it might be useful to quote the docs.